# How to match real numeric coefficients for two expression in Sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy

If you look at this example:
2Bsin(x)+ (B + ¾A)*cos(x) = sin(x) + 2cos(x)
it’s easy to see that
2B = 1, B + ¾A = 2
and applying some basic linear algebra
B = ½, A = 2
In Python, using ***sympy***, however, you run this code:

```
from sympy import *; var('x A B')

P1 = (B/2)*sin(x) + (B + 3*A/4)*cos(x)
P2 = sin(x) + 2*cos(x)
solve(Eq(P1, P2), [A,B])
```

you get this

```
[(-2*B*tan(x)/3 - 4*B/3 + 4*tan(x)/3 + 4/3, B)]
```

Is there a way to get the result in terms of A and B?

Comment: Sorry, in which programming language are the unicode quarter fractionals legal syntax?  Because the code you're showing isn't valid Python code. So please: edit your post and show real code. _Especially_ for the "just showing what I'm talking about" code. No `2B` or `¾A`: show real code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans They’re just for the math examples, I’m obviously not using them in the actual code.

Comment: If you're not using it in your code, don't show it, [show actual code](/help/how-to-ask). Welcome to Stackoverflow: please follow the posting guidelines, and please, show real code because this is a programming Q&A website. The people reading your question expect to see code they recognize. There is no reason to embellish for the sake of a post =)

Comment: Alex, I guess what you are getting at is to apply the method of undetermined coefficients, matching up the coefficients of sin(x) and of cos(x) and then solving for those. You might search for a function to do just that. You might try asking on the Sympy user forum (on Google Groups if I remember correctly).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have to wonder where your hectoring imprecations are coming from; OP has shown a perfectly clear example of "real code".

Comment: @RobertDodier Indeed: their post is fine now. It was not when I commented. There's an edit history.

Comment: Thanks @RobertDodier I’d would try that. Sympy, indeed, has a function for solving differential equations using that method. It’s just that I wanted to take a step-by-step approach. If you know the actual link for the Sympy user forum, and you’d like to share with us, that’ll be great.

Comment: Take a look at: https://groups.google.com/g/sympy

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I dunno. The edit history shows that the Python code was present in the original version, and has not been changed since then, except to replace a quote mark.

Comment: @RobertDodier Of course, that's not what the comments were about. They were about `2B + ¾A` presented with code formatting, suggesting they were programming code, which isn't code in _any_ programming language (except maybe wolfram alpha, which has probably the most permissible parser in existence). But let's stop this: the post is fine now. Let's move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a little bit of a hack but works. I substitute `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` by `x` and `y` and turn it into a polynomial. Then I can just get the coefficients, make an equation out of those and solve it just fine.

```
from sympy import *; var('x y A B')

P1 = (B/2)*sin(x) + (B + 3*A/4)*cos(x)
P2 = sin(x) + 2*cos(x)
P1s = P1.subs({sin(x):x, cos(x):y})
P2s = P2.subs({sin(x):x, cos(x):y})

eqs = tuple(map(lambda x:Eq(*x),zip(Poly(P1s,[x,y]).coeffs(), Poly(P2s,[x,y]).coeffs())))
```

[image: equations]

Those sympy does solve

```
sol = solve(eqs)
```

```
{A: 0, B: 2}
```

And I can even put those into the original equation to see if something weird happened:

```
P1.subs(sol), P2.subs(sol)
```

```
(sin(x) + 2*cos(x), sin(x) + 2*cos(x))
```